# Basic ng-repeat With Simple Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

For the life of me I can not figure out why my simple one dimensional array will not print out using ng-repeat. I've tried a dozen different combinations to the point where I've lost meaning of the `this` keyword.

http://jsfiddle.net/ts8yeynk/1/

```
<body ng-app="test">
    <p>{{ "Hello" + ", world!" }}</p>
    <p>{{ poop }}</p>
    <p>6 + 4 = {{ 6 + 4 }}</p>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as m">
        <div ng-repeat="x in m.linkList">x is: {{x}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in m.list1">x is: {{x}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in m.clown">x is: {{x}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in m.sinkList">x is {{x}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in m.fart">x is {{x}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in m.boom">x is {{x}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
var poop = "Hello, World!";
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var aList = this.list2;
    var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    $scope.boom = [1,2,3,4];


    this.clown = list2;

    fart = [1,2,3,4];

    $scope.linkList = list2;
    $scope.sinkList = [1, 2, 3,4];
});


var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var list2 = [that, there, and, overe, here];
```

Honestly I'm just trying everything. I have such a hard time debugging angular.

What on Gods green earth am I doing wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `controller as` syntax - you reference `this` in your controller, and not `$scope`:

```
//In the controller
this.linkList = [1,2,3,4];
```

View:

```
<p ng-repeat="x in linkList">{{x}}</p>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ts8yeynk/2/

If you check the console, you can see the errors coming up (`that` isn't defined, etc, etc)

Comment: He also needs to quote the strings in the list2 array.

Answer (score 0):

And when not using the `controller as` syntax I would reference `$scope` as so:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.theList = list1;
});

var list1 = [1,2,3,4];
```

**view**

```
<body ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="j in theList">{{ j }}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```